# what is the correct way to use coffeescript with ember´s Mixins?

Tags: ember.js, coffeescript

Apologies for my english,

I am trying to extend a View with a mixin. The code is coffeescript :

### View - films_film_view.js.coffee

```
App.FilmsFilmView = Em.View.extend App.ModalViewMixin,

  templateName: 'films/show'
```

### Mixin - modal_view_mixin.js.coffee

```
App.ModalViewMixin = Em.Mixin.create

  modalView: null

  click: ->
    @showModalView()

  close: ->
    @closeModalView()


  closeModalView: ->
    if @modalView
      @modalView.close()


  showModalView: ->
    @closeModalView()
    @modalView = @createModalView()
    if @modalView
      @modalView.append()
```

when i try to load the app, the app throws this error:

```
Assertion failed: Expected hash or Mixin instance, got [object Undefined]
```

so, what is the correct way to write this ?

Thanks in advance

**Update:**

Solved with :

```
App.ModalViewMixin = Em.Mixin.create

  modalView: null

  click: ->
    @showModalView()

  close: ->
    @closeModalView()


  closeModalView: ->
    if @modalView
      @modalView.close()


  showModalView: ->
    @closeModalView()
    @set modalView, @createModalView()
    if @modalView
      @modalView.append()



App.FilmsFilmView = Em.View.extend App.ModalViewMixin,

  templateName: "films/show"
```

Looks like when the app loads "FilmsFilmView", the mixin still is not initialized and it causes the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happen because when running:

```
App.FilmsFilmView = Em.View.extend(App.ModalViewMixin, ...
```

`App.ModalViewMixin` is undefined, it have to be defined before of it usage.

Ensure that `App.ModalViewMixin` appears before than `App.FilmsFilmView`.

Comment: I have the app in diferents folder, but if i refactor the code to join all in one file and now it works.