# Ember Mixin undefined in controller

Tags: ember.js, coffeescript, mixins

May be a silly question, but can't seem to get this right. I have some actions that I'd like to share across two controllers, so I'd like to define them in a mixin and then include them in the controllers. My syntax matches what I've seen in the guides:

mixins/shared.js.coffee

```
Dashboard.Shared = Ember.Mixin.create
  actions:
    showTab: (tab) ->
      //handle action here
```

controllers/messages/messages_contacts_show_controller.js.coffee

```
Dashboard.MessagesContactsShowController = Ember.ObjectController.extend Dashboard.Shared,
```

Upon loading the app, I have this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: Expected hash or Mixin instance, got [object Undefined]
```

I'm not sure how to load this mixin before the controller since my files are separate (ref: [what is the correct way to use coffeescript with ember´s Mixins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18157171/what-is-the-correct-way-to-use-coffeescript-with-ember%C2%B4s-mixins)--I)'ve tried importing it but keep getting "reserved word" errors from coffeescript.

```
import { Shared } from './mixins/shared'
```

and

```
import Shared from "./mixins/shared"
```

What's the proper way to get a mixin to load before the controllers it will be used in??

I'm using Ember 1.8.1

Comment: Is `App.Shared` a typo?

Comment: You're specifying `Dashboard.Shared` in your call to `Ember.ObjectController.extend`, whereas you're defining `App.Shared`. So `Dashboard.Shared` is undefined, which is what Ember is trying to tell you as clearly as it can.

Comment: @Kingpin2k Correct. Dashboard is the namespace used throughout the app.

Comment: @Kingpin2k (and I only mistyped it in my S.O. post...it's Dashboard.Shared in the code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you `require` your JS files in some main `App` script, the problem is most likely that "MessagesContactsShowController" sorts before "Shared".  When you `require` with a wildcard, the files are included in alpha order.  You might try moving your `Shared` mixin to a different folder and then changing the order of your `require` statements so it is processed before `MessagesContactsShowController`

Comment: Excellent! Because I am not using ember-cli, I had to import the mixin from my namespace. application.js.coffee imports my vendor files, including ember and ember-data, then my dashboard.js.coffee file needed the addition of #require_tree ./mixins to come before the controller. Thanks!